# Internet Explorer Not Position Correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

We have environment ribbons for our different environments. I am adding the ribbons to a new application, however, they are not working.

The following is the relevant code (taken directly from "View Source" on the page). Note that I replaced our web address with `...`.

```
<style> 
    .ribbonBanner { 
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px; 
        top: 0px; 
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        z-index: 99999;
    } 
</style> 

<img border="0" class="ribbonBanner" alt="Development" title="Development" src="http://.../ribbon_dev.gif" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);"/>
```

This code is the same as all of our other apps. However, Internet Explorer is being....well, Internet Explorer. :P

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

**Internet Explorer**

[image: IE]

Anyone have any clue what might be going on?

FYI: I am on IE8

Comment: does the black rectangle above the banner in IE8 have a z-index value lower than the banner? does it have a z-index value at all?

Comment: Nope. No set z-index on that `<div>`.

Comment: try giving it one, with lower value of course, maybe that will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has issues with Position Fixed but I believe it should work in ie8 if you have the correct Doctype. I believe this DocType will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Comment: Yep. our doesn't have a doctype. Just starts with `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`. I will see if I can update that, but I don't think I can.

Comment: Doctype is a separate declaration about the <html> tag. It's used to tell the browser how to interpret the HTML. HTML5 uses `<!Doctype html>`

Comment: Yeah. I know. But it's a struts application with JSPs. Not sure how it gets injected. I am a Spring person.

Comment: Created a test file with no other context. Failed to position correctly without the `<!DOCTYPE>` but worked with the HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Now just to figure out how to insert that into our app. +1. Thanks for the help.